# Proof by cases for sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove by cases that for any two sets $A$ and $B$

$A \subseteq B$ if and only if $A\cup(B\setminus A)=B$

I don't get what cases should I consider, I am thinking of proving it by definition of sets, subsets, and union. Can someone help me understand what is needed from me?

Comment: The cases to prove would be  LHS $\to$ RHS, and RHS $\to$ LHS, where LHS refers to the portion on the left of the biconditional, and RHS means right side of the biconditional.  (if and only if: $\iff$)

Comment: $If A \cup (B - A) = B, then  
A \subseteq A \cup (B - A) = B.  
  
If A subset B, then:  
B = (B \cap A) \cup (B - A) \subseteq A \cup (B - A)  
\subseteq B \cup (B - A) \subseteq B.  
  
Thus B = A \cup (B - A).$

Answer (score 0):

The $A\cup(B\setminus A)$ naturally translates into a disjunction. To be specific, if $x \in A\cup(B\setminus A)$ then $x \in A$ or $x \in B\setminus A$.  So that's where the proof by cases will come in.

Comment: But the point is, that we also need to prove that (1)  $(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \Rightarrow (x\in A\cup (B\setminus A)),$ as well as (2) $(x \in (A\cup(B\setminus A))\Rightarrow (x \in A \rightarrow x\in B))$

Comment: Your answer addresses only $(2)$, and I believe the cases involve $\Rightarrow$, $\Leftarrow$, i.e., Case $(1)$, Case $(2)$

Comment: @amWhy True ... but the 'proof by cases' is typically used for a specific proof technique involving a disjunction. So going one way you would use a proof by cases but (it looks like) not going the other way.

Comment: To be removed..